# How should the items on the noticeboard in the synagogue be arranged?

Tags: halacha, minhag, synagogue, parsha-torah-portion

On a board where the name of the week’s parsha and the relevant additions in the prayers are  displayed as shown [here for example](http://www.ahuva.com/jewish-gifts/pc/Prayer-Times-Synagogue-Board-143p3038.htm#.UXMbT0qU8U1), is there an order of placing the items accepted by halacha or minhag?

For example, I have seen the name of the parsha either at the top or at the bottom.

Comment: Tadir vsaino tadir...

Comment: In my Shul the items that remain the longest are on top, and those being changed constantly remain at the bottom. So Mashiv HaRuach is on top and the Parsha is at the bottom. To the best of my knowledge there is no required order. Everyone does what works for them.

Comment: Interestingly, we don't usually put up the "yaale v'yavo" piece up when it is Rosh Hodesh because we assume that the "Rosh Hodesh" one is sufficient to remind people that we have yaale v'yavo.

Comment: Of course, there is no halacha to have any notice board at all, so why would you assume that if you have one there are any halachot on its order? But, from what I have seen, the name of the parsha tends to be first. Then the more "common" parts are listed next with the new / temporary ones near the bottom. So *Mashiv Haru'ach* which lasts about 6 months goes near the top, then *Ten Tal Umatar* and, *Ya'aleh Veyavo* which lasts at most 5 consecutive weekdays (outside Israel) would be near the bottom. IMO, the announcements are still needed. Few remember to view the board just before davening.